# Apply multi-prompt validation in Cognos

Tags: javascript, cognos

I have three text prompts and want to validate them as a group, requiring the user to input value in one or more prompts before proceeding.

For e.g. I have **First Name**, **Last Name** and **Student ID** fields and want to group these together such that the user has to input value in at-least one prompt before proceeding.  Here is what I have so far, but it is not recognizing the value in second and third fields.

```
var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');

var fName = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('FirstName');
var lName = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('LastName');
var studentId = oCR.prompt.getControlByName('StudentID');

var prompts = [fName ,lName ,studentId];

var i = 0;
var promptsLength = prompts.length;

for ( i = 0; i < promptsLength ; i++) {
            prompts[i].setValidator(validate);
}

function validate() {
    var result = false;
    for ( i = 0; i < promptsLength; i++) {
        if (prompts[i].getValues().length > 0) {
            result = true;
        }
        if (prompts[i] != this) {
            prompts[i].checkData();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Here is some documentation about prompts and java script.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-reporting-scripting_techniques-page673/index.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/reporting/advanced_report_design/page583.html

Comment: Here is some general documention about cascading prompts.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_define_prompt_control.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_cr_rptstd_wrkdat_create_cascading_prompt.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-create-cascading-prompt-cognos-report-studio

Comment: FM has built into it UI for creating cascading prompts, just for your information.

Comment: What version of Cognos?  If 11.x, interactive viewer or compatible viewer?